# How to get substring from the end?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a table with a column called A, which has two records:

```
a2 2014 weather
2016 LNT
```

The target table has two columns.  I want to populate  one column with 'weather', 'LNT' and the other column with '2016', 'a2 2014'.

How can I write a transformation expression using `substr()` and `instr()` to achieve this?

Comment: Is it always going to contain those two values? I am guessing not. Then first you need to identify the pattern in the source data? For example, the last column will not contain any space and the last space can be used as a delimiter? Or it might be, anything after four consecutive digits (2014) would be considered as the second column?

Answer (score 1):

The trick with `instr()` is to use a negative offset, which starts the counting from the end our string.  So `instr(col1, ' ', -1)` will locate the last space in COL1.

My solution uses a WITH clause simply because we need to use the output from the `instr()` in two `substr()` calls:

```
SQL> insert into t42
  2  with cte as (select A, instr(A, ' ', -1) offset
  3               from t23)
  4  select substr(cte.A, 1, cte.offset-1) as c1
  5         , substr(cte.A, cte.offset+1) as c2
  6  from cte
  7  /

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from t42
  2  /

COL1            COL2
--------------- ---------------
a2 2014         weather
2016            LNT

SQL>
```